# Container with BoxLayout is resized by component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm currently working on a project for my studies and I have a little problem concerning the GUI.

Here is some code:

```
private JButton zoomUp, zoomDown;
private JComboBox fractalList;
private JLabel choice,space;
private JPanel ui,display;
private JFrame window;
    public FractalView(FractalModel m, FractalController c, String title, int size_X, int size_Y)
    { 
    window =new JFrame();
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setSize(size_X,size_Y);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    ui=new JPanel();        
    ui.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    ui.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Interface de Controle et Options"));
    BoxLayout uiLayout = new BoxLayout(ui, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    ui.setLayout(uiLayout);
    ui.setMaximumSize(ui.getPreferredSize());

    zoomUp = new JButton("Zoom +");
    zoomUp.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    zoomUp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    ui.add(zoomUp);
    zoomDown = new JButton("Zoom -");
    //ui.add(zoomDown);
    choice = new JLabel("Choisir une fractale : ");
    //ui.add(choice);
    Object[] elements = new Object[]{"Mandelbrot", "Julia", "Buddhabrot"};
    fractalList = new JComboBox<Object>(elements);
    //fractalList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    fractalList.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    fractalList.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE,20));
    //ui.add(fractalList);



    gbc.weighty=1;
    gbc.ipadx=300;
    gbc.gridheight=1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;

    window.add(ui,gbc);

    display=new JPanel();
    display.setBackground(Color.RED);
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.gridheight=1;
    gbc.gridwidth=1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    window.add(display,gbc);
    window.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The problem comes from `JPanel ui` . As long it is empty the size is as desired. But when I add any component to it it's weight increases.

I tried to use `setMaxSize()` but even though it gets resized and this could cause problem with what I want to display on `JPanel display`. I would prefer to avoid using `GridBagLayout` again.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: 1) *"Here is some code:"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) *"I would prefer to avoid using `GridBagLayout` again."* Reads like *"I would prefer to avoid screwdrivers, should I just hit the screw with a hammer again?"*. Use the right tool for the job. I'm not sure if that is GBL here, but don't rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split the Frame and don't want to fight with GridBagLayout, you could just use a BorderLayout.

Then, add one panel to BorderLayout.WEST and the other one to the BorderLayout.EAST position. And remember to call setPreferredSize to fix your desired width and height.

I've made some changes to your code. Check it out:

```
public class TestFrame {
    private JButton zoomUp, zoomDown;
    private JComboBox fractalList;
    private JLabel choice, space;
    private JPanel ui, display;
    private JFrame window;

    public TestFrame(String title, int size_X, int size_Y) {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setSize(size_X, size_Y);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ui = new JPanel();
        ui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size_X/2,size_Y));
        ui.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        ui.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Interface de Controle et Options"));
        BoxLayout uiLayout = new BoxLayout(ui, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        ui.setLayout(uiLayout);

        zoomUp = new JButton("Zoom +");
        // zoomUp.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        zoomUp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        ui.add(zoomUp);
        zoomDown = new JButton("Zoom -");
         ui.add(zoomDown);
        choice = new JLabel("Choisir une fractale : ");
         ui.add(choice);
        Object[] elements = new Object[] { "Mandelbrot", "Julia", "Buddhabrot" };
        fractalList = new JComboBox<Object>(elements);
        // fractalList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        // fractalList.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        fractalList.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, 20));
         ui.add(fractalList);

        window.add(ui, BorderLayout.WEST);

        display = new JPanel();
        display.setBackground(Color.RED);
        display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size_X/2,size_Y));

        window.add(display, BorderLayout.EAST);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame("test of BorderLayout with WEST and EAST", 800, 600);
    }
}
```

If you need something more complex than that, you could go with [miglayout](http://miglayout.com).